# AWS Container Healthcheck

Tags: python, amazon-ecs

I have an AWS service running loads of containers. I was wondering if its possible to make a python script that checks for the container health.

I know i can run commands for healthcheck so in theory i could run a python script that exits `sys.exit(0)` or 1 depending on the healthcheck, does that makes sense?

Would it be possible to make a python script for a healthcheck? Would I need just to call the script on the healthcheck task?

Thanks for any info!

Comment: Which AWS service are you using?

Comment: ECS service, im not that familiar with aws so I hope thats the correct answer ? xD

Comment: Why do you want to write custom healthchecks if there are already the ECS ones for the running tasks?

Comment: I need a script that checks for specific stuff checked in my code.

Comment: You can use [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.describe_container_instances) to list and describe containers.

Comment: could you resolve this question?

Comment: I couldnt solve properly. I was wondering how could a python return sys 0 or sys 1 could be the healthcheck. 
For the time i made an endpoint just for this, but its cludgy, i wonder if i could do it with a simply python script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create your custom ECS Health check command using python and execute it via Shell. Below example has curl command running within container, you will need to run your python script instead of curl script.

```
[ "CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost/ || exit 1" ]
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_HealthCheck.html

You need to make sure your python script return 0 part of successful execution. If you have tried something like with python then please share the details around difficulties you had.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me

```py
[ "CMD-SHELL", "python -c \"import sys; sys.exit(0)\"" ]
```